# minerd disappears when i try to launch it with a batch file?

Tags: litecoin

I started using pooler cpuminer v 2.3.3 yesterday and it works.
Today, it doesn't. I have no idea what the problem is, when I open the batch file, the minerd file disappears.

This is my command line thing:
http://pastebin.com/DyqstLrn

**UPDATE:** The thing that was causing the problem was Malwarebytes Anti-Malware. It works fine now, thanks for every one's support!

Comment: What do you mean by "the minerd file disappears"? It is deleted from its directory?

Comment: disappears as in it got deleted somehow

Comment: If you copy the minerd file back into the directory and run the script again, does it get deleted again?

Comment: it disappears every time I copy and run it

Comment: This is very strange. But I think the explanation provided by jamd315 is quite plausible. Antivirus software looks for mining programs because they are often used by viruses to hijack people's computers and mine without their knowledge.

Comment: I disable my antivirus every time I run it and turn it back on but it still does that, so I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 2):

This is probably your antivirus either deleting or quarantining it.  Depending on your antivirus, you need to manually trust minerd.exe and/or restore it from quarantine.

I use Norton 360.  To unquarantine with Norton

1. Open Norton
2. Click tasks at the top
3. Click "Check Security History" on the left
4. Find minerd.exe, it might be easier to re-extract or re-download
5. Click more details
6. Click restore at the bottom

Comment and I will try for other antiviruses

Comment: avast antivirus?

Comment: I googled and found this as easiest to understand http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZcWsAcA8dU

Comment: I removed it from the chest and added it to the exclusions but still after I run it, it disappears.

Comment: Can you show me the contents of the file?